# TCL - Error in startup script: expected integer but got "Sans"

Tags: qt, tcl

I am trying to run a tcl script using `wish` as
`$ wish main.tcl`
output of the command is

```
 Error in startup script: expected integer but got "Sans"
    (database entry for "-font" in widget ".menubar")
    invoked from within
"menu .menubar"
    (procedure "CreateGui" line 11)
    invoked from within
"CreateGui"
    (file "./rshift.vfs/lib/app-shift/shift.tcl" line 215)
    invoked from within
"source ./rshift.vfs/lib/app-shift/shift.tcl"
    ("package ifneeded app-shift 1.0" script)
    invoked from within
"package require app-shift"
    (file "rshift.vfs/main.tcl" line 57)
```

any way to fix this ?

Comment: probably, but you're not showing your code. We need to see where you create the `.menubar` widget. I suspect you forgot some quotes.

Comment: Follow the [`menu`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm) man page to the [`-font`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/options.htm#M-font) option to the [`font`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/font.htm) man page to the [Font Descriptions](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/font.htm#M13) section. It looks like you intended usage #1 but actually specified #3

Answer (score 0):

after spending hours on it, I found the fix. I just commented `*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline-10:pixelsize=30` in `~/.Xresources` and Surprisingly, I am able to use the script without any issue.

may be `tk` is confused with the extra parameters `-10:pixelsize=30` in font name.

**hint**:  use `xrdb ~/.Xresources` to reload.